# Merge multiple DataFrames in an efficient manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have plenty of DataFrames need to be merged by `axis=0`, it's important to find some fast way to do this op.

So far, I try `merge` and `append`, but these functions all need assignment after merging like `df = df.append(df2)` and will become slower and slower, is there some another method which can merge in place and more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframes have the same index, you can use `pd.concat`:

```
In [61]: df1
Out[61]: 
   a
0  1

In [62]: df2
Out[62]: 
   b
0  2
```

Create a list of dataframes:

```
In [63]: df_list = [df1, df2]
```

Now, call `pd.concat`:

```
In [64]: pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
Out[64]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
```

Comment: but how did the dataframes merge in concat? Isn't it use assignment?

Comment: @danche You didn't provide any examples, so I assumed this is what you want.

Comment: Assume there are ABCDE etc. Dataframes, this can put these dataframe in `[A,B,C,D,E]` list and concat it. Is it faster than merge AB then merge ABC then ABCD..?.

Comment: @danche 10000% percent yes. One thing to note is that merge will merge on common columns. This will simply concatenate the dataframes without any such join logic, so it is much faster.

Comment: I'll try your method, Thanks! As there are 2 million dataframes to be concatenated, it will help a lot if it works!

Comment: @danche If all you want to do is a horizontal join, then this will work. Just make sure the index is the same. If not, you must call `df.reset_index()` and then concatenate. If it works, please mark accepted. Thanks.